# Sprite-Sheet BLIT with HTML 5 Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, blit, sprite-sheet

Looking for an example of someone doing a a sprite sheet BLIT with javascript and the HTML 5 Canvas tag.

I've been looking at [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) a bit, but I haven't found a clear cut example of how to do it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example of blitter using Canvas and JS:
http://glowfilter.com/blog/jblitter-animated-html5-canvas-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

Check out this js/html5/canvas game engine for platform games:

http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/

I don't know if this is over complicated but all his source is on github.

Comment: I looked at this. He definitely supports Sprite-Sheets. But I'm pretty enamored with Processing.js. I think worst case scenario if there isn't a straight forward way of doing this with Processing I will examine Akihabara's source and possibly try to incorporate both. Thanks for the reply, I'll mark this as an answer if another sample isn't posted.